# MudbLazor MudSwitch component - How to invoke a function?

Tags: mudblazor

```
<MudSwitch @bind-Value="@Switch1"   ValueChanged="()=>View" Label="Info" Color="Color.Info" />

@code {
private   async Task<bool> View()
{
   //invoke some function.
    return true;
}
}
```

How to invoke a function when the value is changed(switch on/off)? The above code doesnot compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@bind-Value:after="{EVENT}"`:

```
<MudSwitch @bind-Value="@Switch1" @bind-Value:after="View" Label="Info" Color="Color.Info" />

@code {
    private bool Switch1 { get; set; }

    private async Task View()
    {
        //invoke some function.
    }
}
```

Or

```
<MudSwitch T="bool" Value="@Switch1" ValueChanged="View" Label="Info" Color="Color.Info" />

@code {
    private bool Switch1 { get; set; }

    private async Task View(bool newValue)
    {
        Switch1 = newValue;
        //invoke some function.
    }
}
```

Comment: The code didnot work  https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkGSOxuzIsUKtCFe

Comment: The method must return `Task` not `Task<bool>`.

Comment: it doesnot work. please see the above hyperlink